# Find group of automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

In group $ GL(2,R) $ I have subgroup H, generated by 2 elements:
$ a=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}    
$ ,
$ b=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}    
$

I have to find group of automorphisms $ Aut H $

So, I have found out that multiplication of this matrix always gives:

$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}    
$ $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}    
$ =
$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n+m \\ 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}    
$

Order of matrix gives $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n*ord \\ 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}    
$

Am I right that subgroup H is infinite cyclic group? And the only one automorphims is $Z2$ ? I dont get this stuff about automorhisms, to be honest.

Comment: Yes, $H$ is infinite cyclic, and yes, the group of automorphisms of $H$ is isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_2$. But you still have to find that non-identity automorphism.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, is there any? I have no idea about others automorphisms...

Comment: You know the group is (isomorphic to) ${\bf Z}_2$. You know that ${\bf Z}_2$ has two elements, and you know that one of them is the identity, so the other one isn't. So you know there is an automorphism other than the identity. If you know what the non-identity automorphism of $\bf Z$ is, you might be able to figure out what the non-identity automorphism of $H$ is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry for annoyance and stupidity, but I cant find any...

Comment: You can't find a non-identity automorphism of ${\bf Z}$? ${\bf Z}$ is a cyclic group, which means that if you have any homomorphism from it to any group $G$, then when you know where the generator goes, you can determine where everything else goes. So, what's a good generator for ${\bf Z}$? If you know where that generator goes under an automorphism of ${\bf Z}$, then where do the other elements go? What has to happen for the resulting map to be onto? What does that tell you about the non-identity automorphism of ${\bf Z}$? Also, I see this question has been closed as a duplicate [continued]

Comment: [continued] have you looked at that other question that this one duplicates?

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate. The other question was about the integers; this question is about a group of matrices (which happens to be isomorphic to the integers). To those of us who know our way around these things, it's the same question – but at the level on which OP is operating, they are two entirely different questions. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have read a lot of stuff not only on mse, but I still dont properly understand automorphisms( almost half of year already :/ )

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know that non-identity automorphism of Z is negation. But in subgroup H I have only 2 elements what I am supposed to do?

Comment: $H$ has infinitely many elements – it has only two *automorphisms*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ is infinite cyclic,  so isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.  There are only two automorphisms of $\Bbb Z$.

Note that $\Bbb Z$ has two generators,  $1$ and $-1$.  How about sending $1$ to $-1$?

So, in $H$, that would mean $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I understand this about Z, but there arent elements you wrote in subgroup H. I only have 2 elements in my subgroup H or I misunderstood something

Comment: $H$ has infinitely many elements! It is generated by two elements, but it has infinitely many elements. It's the group of automorphisms of $H$ that has only two elements, just like the automorphism group of $\bf Z$ has only two elements (while $\bf Z$ itself has infinitely many elements).

Comment: Okay, thank you lad I got it, but my stupid ass still can't get what should group of automorphisms contain, I have read theory countless times but still have no clue about this...

Comment: Maybe think about the isomorphism $h:\Bbb Z\to H$ given by $h(n)=\begin {pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\,,\forall n\in\Bbb Z$ a little.

Comment: @ChrisCuster I understand this isomorphism $ Z -> G $ but H has only elements generated by 2 , 3, for example there is not element  $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$  in H, so where we send 1 from Z?

Comment: To $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster but how it is possible if H doesnt have this element?

Comment: $H$ does.  This element is $ba^{-1}$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster fk thank you man,I forgot about  inverse elements, so as Z has one non-identity automorphism - negation, same does H group. Thank you very much man, sorry for annoyance.